# PhoneGap - navigator.app.exitApp() Not Working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I'm using Phonegap to make a small application but the `navigator.app.exitApp()?` isn't working at all.

- This is my first hybrid app.
- My target platform is Android 5
- I'm developing on Windows with Cordova CLI.

I call a JavaScript function with this

```
<input type='button' onclick='exitApp();'/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function exitApp() { navigator.app.exitApp(); }
```

Ideas??

Comment: Have you installed notification plugin?

Comment: This one?? cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: This one :- cordova plugin install org.apache.cordova.dialogs

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your on of your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? What platform are you developing on? Windows, MacOS?
Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Jesse I have answered your question on the post. Thanks

Comment: You need to use the @ sign in front of my name  or I cannot see the response. I happened on this by chance. IS THIS YOUR FIRST HYBRID APP?

Comment: yes this is my first app, I only need it to work on Android @JesseMonroy650

Comment: Okay. I have updated your original post. FWIW: *Phonegap Build* is an online build service by Adobe/Phonegap. Your answer will take about 30 minutes. You've asked a very good question, which will do well after they answer is accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it used to be that calling `navigator.app.exitApp()` had just a few stumbling blocks, but now both Google and Apple have thrown in major impediments for developers.

1. Make sure your you wait for the [`deviceready`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) events before you make the call to *exit*. You might consider putting up a splash screen, or greying out (disableing) the button or something until `deviceready` fires and the Cordova library is loaded.
2. This is the *impediment*. You now need to add a [`whitelist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin and for Android add `CSP`. The plugin is required for `CSP`. You can get around this by moving all Javascript (including any `on*=`) and `<style>` (and `style=`) into a separate file. EXCEPTION for `CSP` – using any online resources.

**On #1,**

Add this to your javascript:

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // alert("deviceready");
    document.getElementById('exitApp').addEventListener('click', function() {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    });
}
```

Add this to your index.html:

```
<button id="exitApp">Exit</button>
```

**On #2,** the quick answer is:

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
This *whitelist* worksheet should help when you are ready to be more secure.
[HOW TO: apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
function backKeyDown() {
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?", onConfirm, "Please Confirm", "Yes,No"); 
}
function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing
        return;
    }else{
        navigator.app.exitApp();// Otherwise we quit the app.
    }
}
```

You have to install the following plugin:

```
cordova plugin install org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

Comment: Are today (year 2020) dialog's window necessary to achieve an answer to the main question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can also just add a listener in your device ready callback

```
onDeviceReady: function () {

    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //TODO: throw up your dialog here!
    }, true);

    //other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, I tried to use the simplest idea and nope @weagle08

Comment: odd because that same snippet is in production code with a navigator.app.exitApp(); it it works as expected.  Do you have a very simple project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I made a new project with only that and worked... But in mine wont work.... Weird @weagle08

Comment: are you catching any exceptions? i'm wondering if your object prototype hasn't somehow gotten whacked or maybe you have a listener somewhere catching it and preventing app exit somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just use wherever you need in this line (Ionic 3 exactly working)

**navigator.app.exitApp();**

thats all. enjoy your coding...

Comment: this will just minimize the app not killing the process