# navigator.app.exitApp() not working

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm using intel xdk - cordova, I'm trying to exit from app on tapping back button.But below mentioned code not working,it works only when I add crosswalk in my build settings. I don't want to add crosswalk as it is heavy.Help me to make this code work without crosswalk.

> > jquery

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhoneGap - navigator.app.exitApp() Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144829/phonegap-navigator-app-exitapp-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I selected optimize with crosswalk option in build settings, now it is working fine.